# Assign observable to variable in angular 8

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

In my angular 8 application, I have an api call in a service function which is an observable. The api call is async and takes 2-3 seconds and so I want to display some indicator like an hour glass till the api call is complete. Can I achieve this my awaiting the response and assigning it to a variable? Here is my observable:

```
getCompany(val: string): Observable<string[]> {
return this.http.get<string[]>(`-------myapicall------------`);
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You could set a `loading` flag in your component while you wait for the API call to complete:

```js
getCompany(val: string) {
  this.loading = true

  this.apiService.getCompany(val)
    .subscribe(
      (company) => {
        this.loading = false
      
        // Do something with company data
      },
      (err) => {
        this.loading = false

        // Handle error
      }
    )
}
```

You can then use the `loading` flag in your template to display the hourglass.

NOTE: remember to handle unsubscribing.

Comment: I'd also handle the error case to reset the `loading` flag.

Answer (score 0):

You can always leverage Ngrx state management to perform tasks like this. This way you will efficiently decouple the components and services calling external resources and make it more testable.

You could write actions for *GetCompanyStart, GetCompanySuccess, GetCompanyFailed.*

- then you can write an effect that listens to *GetCompanyStart*, and when that effect recieves the action, it will go ahead an call the relevant method on your service. Once this service returns
- Parallely - a reducer can set the 'loading' flag to true when it recieves the action *GetCompanyStart*.
- A selector on your component does not need to know who or what called the service, all it needs to know is whether the 'loading' flag is true or false - so it can show the spinner (or not).
- when the service returns the data, the effect will dispatch *GetCompanySuccess* action that will be listened to by the reducer, which will set the 'loading' to false ( this will automatically be sent to your component via the selector - because Observables are AWESOME!!) OR it will dispatch *GetCompanyFailed* which will set the *loading* to false - because you don't want the spinner to keep on showing if the api failed.